# How to use multiple accounts of AWS SES for Email Marketing

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

This is about a web startup. We are working on Email Marketing to get more registrations on our Platform. We have more than 1 Million relevant email addresses collected from web scraping (bounce rate is around 5%).

So we are sending inbound (transactional & notification) mails to our users. Apart from that we are also using AWS SES to send outbound invitation mails to scraped email id's. Recently AWS raised question about the nature of mails we are sending. (During ses account creation, i had stated that this ses account will be used for transactional emails only).

My questions are:

1. shall I create another SES account and then verify the same domain or shall i purchase another domain and verify that on in order to send the outbound marketing mails from that account? (I don't want AWS SES to blacklist my domain)
2. How can I send Marketing emails (in bulk amount) via SES given that my bounce rate won't cross 5% normally?
3. How do other startups & Companies using SES handle this problem? What are the best-practices if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is you can't - you are violating the TOS and they will suspend your account if/when they catch you. You have just said you are scraping email addresses from some source and then sending marketing/spam emails. AWS doesn't want you as a customer for this purpose:

> Amazon SES is designed for messages that have been specifically
>   requested by the recipient. The Acceptable Use Policy requires that
>   "You will not distribute, publish, send, or facilitate the sending of
>   unsolicited mass e-mail or other messages, promotions, advertising, or
>   solicitations (like "spam"), including commercial advertising and
>   informational announcements." Amazon SES investigates cases in which
>   messages appear to violate the Acceptable Use Policy or are not
>   desired by the recipient, whether due to being unsolicited or for any
>   other reason.